Samatha meditation continuation problem / lose urge to continue
I know this is not the place for this kind of questions.
But I post this anyway.
I am seeking advice on Samatha meditation.
Time to time, I get strong urge to do Samatha meditation.(I'm not an expert on this).
So,
I start with a combination of Maithree, Anapanasati and Vipassana meditation to cut down five hindrances. At this level, I reach happy state. Then I switch to Kasina meditation. But I can't continue Kasina meditation enough time to reach any static Nimitta. That's because I lose urge to continue / neediness to reach Dhayana.
Sometimes,

I feel full
I feel, can't hold any more fullness ( full pressure)
less neediness to continue

.
So, I feel one or multiple of above and then I can't continue the meditation. Like, I feel like I can't continue anymore. (but I want to).
But through all this, I feel happy. (after Maithree and Vipassana meditation)
So, questions are ,

Why is this happening?
Why I lose urge?
Why sometimes feel full
pressure?
How would I overcome this?


My own idea of the problem is,

maybe I didn't actually reduce the five hindrances evenly, maybe I reduced the 1,2 and 5, but I think, maybe I didn't reduce 3rd and 4th hindrances. (main point).
maybe my Vipassana is too much(for Samatha) and I lose carving(thanha) for Dhayana. (newly added this line).
maybe I don't have enough capacity.
maybe my methods are wrong.

It could be one of above or something else.

Five hindrances > order is as in this article.

Sensory desire (kāmacchanda)
Ill-will (vyāpāda; also spelled byāpāda)
Sloth-and-torpor (thīna-middha)
Restlessness-and-worry (uddhacca-kukkucca)
Doubt (vicikiccha)

Thanks . ☸️.
Any help is appreciated.

It seems, there's no real buddhists here (on this site) to get an advice.(who actually practice anything ; but only contemplate and argue.).  On the other hand, I am the stupid one to think that there will be.

hindrances aren't really numerically ordered..can u use words?

Ok. I updated the question.

This site is not for meditation advice, you need an actual real teacher in real life to explain what is happening as it is happening and to give YOU, the individual meditator direct advise that is suited to you to help you with the present issue. Saying on a website I have "sensual desire", desire for what, why have you had this desire, who or what is the desire etc....its personal practical issues. Every person has their own personal issues that are not a 1 case suits all. Why Buddha said to seek a teacher/spiritual friends. He didn't mean a webiste, or a book

This site is for a reference of Buddhist knowledge, scripture, understandings etc. A site where people can edit answers AND questions to better allign them with the correct answer(s)  Not for indivdual personal advice about personal practice. Hence why the questions are not full of such questions.

If you cannot find a sangha in real life to gain help from, there are online sanghas that do weekly mediations classes, guided meditations etc. More often than not you would be following their teachings.  Either way the best way to get practical advice would be to go and speak to a monk that has experience with what you are experiencing in your local monastery. Or even a Buddhist centre.

Ok. ..............

Its not that people dont want to or even cannot help you, its just this site is neither designed for, or suited for that type of Q&A. Maybe you could find a person to go into chat with you and converse with you about your personal issue, but as I said above your best idea is to speak with a member of the sangha. You can even do this online, many meditation groups do zoom or discord sessions etc. Yuttadhamo does intense at home courses and will help with issues arising (he doesn't do samatha, only satiphathanna) or even bikkhu bodhi does study classes online.  Using them as examples.

Okay. Thanks for the guidance. .

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Remyla you are probably right, it's too nuanced, but personal-practice is actually one of the tags

Feeling full means feeling contented right?
I also find myself in same situation. and give up. Yet not found strong solution.
But I can say that feeling contented is one kind of restlessness. If you treat like that. you may find some solution.
You are meditating perfectly well. discursive thinking gone. You are still. this makes your body relax. this leads you towards feeling good.
And Exactly here the trap of Mara starts. You were supposed to be mindful of the feeling good. its nature of arising and passing away. instead you started feeling good.
The only solution to  this is , making resolution that you will not give up in this situation. kind of adhitthan. you have to make before you start meditating.

Feeling full means feeling contented right? Yes. I find two points in your answer. I will try You were supposed to be mindful of the feeling good. and making resolution that you will not give up in this situation. kind of adhitthan.. Thanks .

The 5 hindrances can arise at any time, in any way, in any order throughout any and all meditation sessions. One needs to apply the antidote as they arise. Its not a simple task of reducing #1 then its gone for that meditation session...it can pop up again...
As with any skill it takes time and effort. One has to apply themselves continuously as a habitual practice. Some times you will have good sessions, some times bad sessions.

Your answer is true. But doesn't answer my specific problems. .

I think you should apply mindfulness(sati) to the problem.
What causes me to feel fullness? Which vedana causes this? Such as "I want to do something else", "It's enough", "It's meaningless" etc. I also assume "fullness" as a unpleasant sensation - this is also a vedana.
Hindrances are not just an obstacle to meditation. They are here to teach you something. Either you don't know how they arise and fall, or you still haven't learned something that is causing them. Or sometimes you take them as "my thoughts"/ my feelings and this sense of self leads more obstacles.
In any case you should try to observe how "Energy(Viriya)" works. Why do you get energy for something and not for the other? How energy increases and how energy decrease. Those who are skilled should be able to maintain whatever energy/Will they want.

Perhaps it has little to do with hindrances directly, but instead, just bad technique (no offense).  The object of meditation has to be right; it has to serve its purpose. If it's not, concentration might be bad, poorly exerted, leading to full pressure or discomfort.  More likely than not, you are not capable of generating the kasina nimitta (efficient cause), which seemingly requires a lot of energy and stability of concentration. That's why Buddha probably recommended the breath, for its presence and availability.

Ok. I will take your suggestions also into consideration. which seemingly requires a lot of energy and stability of concentration. yes. That's why I use Anapanasati(breath) to strengthen some concentration before moving to Kasina.

@Pycm what is your kasina?

Blue, Nilo Kasina.

This question is about a craving based meditation technique, which makes progress impossible. The Buddha would not have taught about Hindu kasina. The suttas (maybe one or two only) about kasina appear fake. The Buddha taught a Path that is about giving up craving (SN 56.11; SN 48.9; MN 118). Obviously the questioner is not practicing the Anapanasati Sutta (as they believe they are). The Anapanasati Sutta literally says at its very end that mindfulness depends on giving up craving (vossagga).

a monk develops mindfulness as a factor for awakening dependent on
seclusion, dependent on dispassion, dependent on cessation, resulting
in relinquishment (vossagga).
MN 118

'Anapanasati' means 'mindfulness with breathing'. This means when the mind is continuously mindful to maintain an absence of craving, the breathing will automatically appear in the consciousness of the mind.
